What publications are "conference proceedings?"
I'm trying to figure out what things count as "conference proceedings," so I can clearly distinguish them from normal peer-reviewed articles.
Are special issues of a normal journal which publish a set of papers from a conference counted as "conference proceedings?"
Thank you everyone!

This probably depends on the field. In CS, for example, many conferences publish proceedings that contain the papers and other material presented at the conference. These are available by subscription, usually by membership in the sponsoring organization. This makes all of the work of the conference available widely even to those who don't attend.
Papers presented at conferences in CS are actually peer reviewed, though a bit less formally than with journals. The reviewers may be self selecting and the conference committee (or part of it - the program committee) serve as the editorial board). But there is vetting of articles and some are rejected. There are also workshops that are vetted as a whole, but it might be that not every presentation has prior review.
I suspect that in other fields, conference proceedings might have narrower distribution, namely to attendees. CS may be a bit of an outlier in this as conference presentation is deemed very important in that field. Other fields prefer journal publication.
And, yes, some journals will publish conference proceedings as special issues via an arrangement between the journal and the conference sponsors.
That is at least three models. But literally, the proceedings are a record of the official work and outcomes of the conference. They might be finalized prior to the conference so that they are available to attendees.
It might be quite different in your field, especially if it is Biblical Studies or related. Some "conferences" are just fairly informal get-togethers for discussion. There the proceedings might be gathered during the conference itself and published afterwards for attendees or a wider audience. That would be a fourth model.

This is very helpful--thank you very much!
